# Sharepoint 2010 next page arrow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a large site collection with many users and groups.  When I go to see a list of users of a group, I can see the first page with list of 30 users. On the bottom of the page there is an arrow to navigate to the next page, but instead of going to the next page, it went to the Site Homepage.  Other site collections on the same farm and even other page in the same Site do not have this problem.  I am using Sharepoint 2010. Any idea what caused this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the thing which cause it for this particular list, but it may happen if the list is corrupted, so My opinion is to make an Stp if the list with the include content if possible and then try delete this group and recreate it using the same stp.

I hope this help and please let me know the output.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to create a new group with the same members, the problem still exist. I havent tried to create any Stp yet.

Comment: it works!! thanks for your help. And I found another more simple solution to change the View item limit in the List setting. 

Thanks!